# Find all $f(x)$ such that $f(f(x)+1) = x^4 + 4x + 5$

Tags: functions, polynomials

I have been looking at some problems from old books recently and got stuck on this one. I have been experimenting to find some functions and it seemed to be very close to $f(x) = x^2 + 1$. However, I am not sure what the best way to go about this problem is. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for any function $f$ or specifically for polynomials? In that second case, it's evident you'll need a monic quadratic polynomial, so just plug in $f(x)=x^2+ax+b$ and solve for $a$ and $b$ by comparing coefficients

Comment: @Mastrem Specifically polynomials

Comment: Thank you... Now that I retried I reached the same solution of $f(x)=x^2+1$. After retrying it actually worked. It turned out I just made a small error while using f(x).

Comment: $f(x)=x^2+1$ gives $x^4+4x^2+5$ not $4x$, unless the title was wrongly written.